# Maximum number of groups in Linux

Tags: linux, groups

I have several questions about linux groups

1. Is there a limit to the number of groups a user can create?
2. Is there a limit to the total number of groups in a system?
3. Is there a limit to the number of groups a user may be a member of?
4. Do large numbers of groups (and users as well) degrade performance? Will 1000 users with 1000 groups each be substantially slower than 1 user and no groups (discluding system generated users/groups)

I'm trying to come up with a website that bridges the gap between SQL user databses and actual linux users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Users can't create groups, only the superuser can. And the superuser can create up to the system maximum minus existing groups.
2. Modern Linuxes have a 32-bit `gid_t`, so just short of 4.3e9.
3. Depends completely on the NSS being used. I don't think the `files` NSS has a limit.
4. Again, depends on the NSS. Using something like LDAP would be faster than `files` obviously.

Comment: How do I find out what my 'system maximum' is. I read [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/peteh/date/20050614) it is 16 or 32...that is pitiful if it's the case.

Comment: Why are you reading Solaris documentation when you've tagged the question "linux"?

Comment: that's a relief, but the article says `You simply cannot have more than 16 groups and use AUTH_SYS`. It seems the problem is more complicated than at first glance.

Comment: I got linked to that page from another linux site.

Comment: So then don't use NFSv2 or v3.